# TextField Material-ui are not working properly reactjs and windows 10

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, textfield

I am trying to replicate TextField example from material-ui this is how is suppose to be

[This is how should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/574k1.png)

but i got this

[marks in red is to show extra line that all TextFiel has[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aI1iv.png)

do you know the reasons?

Comment: It would be really good if you can explain a bit more about, what you have tried so far? or explain your code and the issue that you facing with it.

Comment: thanks for you reply @manish. but after many test i got the same problem and i deduced that this issue is related to my webpack and babel configuration.  if i use the react installation npx create-react-app appname the material-ui library works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please write a component like **TextFieldExample** and use this in **app** Component.

```
import React from 'react';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';

export default function TextFieldExample(props) {
  return (
    <TextField id="standard-basic" label={props.label} variant={props.variant}  />
  );
}
```

Here is the **App** Component Code that includes how you can use **TextFieldExample** Component. Here you can pass label and variant as an props and use it in **TextFieldExample** Component

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import TextFieldExample from "./TextFieldExample";

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <TextFieldExample label="Standard"/>
                <TextFieldExample label="Filled" variant="filled" />
                <TextFieldExample label="Outlined" variant="outlined" />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));

export default App;
```

I include the output image for your understanding.
[image: output image]

Comment: thanks for you reply @khabir . but after many test i got the same problem and i deduced that this issue is related to my webpack and babel configuration.  if i use the react installation npx create-react-app appname the material-ui library works fine.

Comment: Yes may be it is your environment issue.